# Why is the falling factorial $x^{(n)} = 1$, when $n = 0$?

Tags: number-theory

Defining the "falling factorial" as $x^{(n)}$ = $x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n+1)$ for any $x \in \Bbb C$, I encounter that $x^{(0)} = 1 $ and I have no idea why this is true! Is this a definition similar to the definition that $0! = 1$ ? Thanks.

Comment: This is the base case so that we can define the recurrence $x^{(n)} = x(x-1)^{(n-1)}$. We want $(x+1)^{(1)} = x+1 = (x+1)x^{(0)}$, so clearly $x^{(0)}=1$.

Comment: Also $0!$ isn't $1$ by definition, if you look at the formula of factorial which is $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ then you will see that $\Gamma(1)$ actually integrates to 1.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar nice thanks for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) uses a different notation for the same, using $(x)_n$ for the falling factorial. Note that the usual factorial is related to the falling factorial when $x=n$ as: $$n!=(n)_n$$

So, $n=0 \implies ?$

Comment: Is this not different since in your case we would have $(n)_n$, whereas my case $(x)_n$ is such that $x$ and $n$ can be different?

Comment: @IntegrateThis Well, it was good to relate $0!=1$ with the falling factorial definition as well.